# Simplify method: Merge two Options to one result

Tags: scala

Can this be simplified? The return value should be `Option[State]`.

```
updateStateOne(state, "SomeData") match {
    case Some(updatedState) => Some(updateStateTwo(updatedState, "SomeOtherData").getOrElse(updatedState))
    case None               => updateStateTwo(state, "SomeOtherData")
}
```

I wonder if it's possible without the `match ... case`?

Comment: Your `match` cases don't return the same type. One is `Some[Option[State]]` while the other is `Option[State]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little hard to tell, but I think this is what you want:

```
updateStateOne(state, "SomeData").fold(updateStateTwo(state, "SomeOtherData")
                                      )(s => updateStateTwo(s, "SomeOtherData"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `fold` as mentioned in other answers, or `orElse`:

```
updateStateOne(state, "SomeData").orElse(Some(state)).map(updateStateTwo(_,"SomeOtherData"))
```

Or `map` and `getOrElse` (which is completely equivalent to `fold`):

```
updateStateOne(state, "SomeData").map(s => updateStateTwo(s, "SomeOtherData")).getOrElse(updateStateTwo(state, "SomeOtherData"))
```

At the end of the day, it depends on your style preferences and on what your team finds more readable.

Answer (score 1):

```
def update[S](f: (S, String) => Option[S]): (S, String) => S =
     (state, data) => f((state, data)).getOrElse(state)

val s1 = update(updateStateOne)(state, "SomeData")
val s2 = update(updateStateTwo)(s1, "SomeOtherData")
```